# Jetpack Compose Vertical Staggered Grid with variable width

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

i am new to jetpack compose the dont know if this is achievable or not.

so i have a list of strings and i want to show them in a staggered grid where each item should be placed in the current row unless it doesn't fit then it should be placed in the next row.

if i try to do this with `LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid` the items are not variable in width so if a text has more characters then its height gets increased.

if i do this with `LazyHorizontalStaggeredGrid` the width of the item is fine but they go outside the view and makes the layout scrollable

how can i achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no lazy, i.e. RecyclerView style layout for this, but if you are dealing with a reasonable amount of items, it sounds like [FlowRow](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/flow) is what you are looking for